# What are the truthy and falsy values in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I think it will be considered in the context of `ng-show` or `ng-class`?  Are there other situations?  It seems truthy and falsy are different from pure JavaScript slightly -- but the only one exception I know of so far is `[]` -- which is truthy in JavaScript but falsy in AngularJS.

(actually, I tried using AngularJS 1.2.1 and `[]` is falsy, while on AngularJS 1.4.8 and 1.5.0, `[]` is truthy.  see https://jsfiddle.net/6ayaLhbk/ ,  https://jsfiddle.net/6ayaLhbk/1/ , and https://jsfiddle.net/6ayaLhbk/2/)

I think it has a catch that one may think `ng-show="ctrl.foo"` is the same as `ng-hide="!ctrl.foo"` but in the case of Angular 1.2.1, it is not.  To get the identical result of pure JavaScript in Angular 1.2.1, seems like we can use `ng-show="!!ctrl.foobar"` https://jsfiddle.net/6ayaLhbk/3/

If it is `ng-class` in Angular 1.2.1, then it seems like it goes back to the pure JS truthy and falsy rule: https://jsfiddle.net/6ayaLhbk/5/

Comment: Related to `[]`: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3969

Comment: If we could get a dollar for every intelligent downvoter here...

Comment: Hey, 太極者無極而生! :) Sorry for any misunderstanding, but you said that [] is a truthy value in Javascript?
I am a little confuse because when I test

`[] == ""`
`[] == 0`
`[] == false`

I get true for all the cases.

Comment: @ebragaparah no, you need to use `===`, or do this: `console.log(!![])` or do this: `if ([]) console.log("ok");`

Comment: you're right! on this link [1] I could realize what you're saying. thanks :D

[1]: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20%26%20going/ch2.md#truthy--falsy

Answer (score 4):

The following values are always falsy:

- false
- 0 (zero)
- "" (empty string)
- null
- undefined
- NaN (a special Number value meaning Not-a-Number!)

> All other values are truthy, including "0" (zero in quotes), "false"
>   (false in quotes), empty functions, empty arrays, and empty objects.

```
var a = !!(0); // variable is set to false
var b = !!("0"); // true
```

**Comparing Falsy Values**
Falsy values follow some slightly odd comparison rules which can lead to errors in program logic.

The falsy values false, 0 (zero), and "" (empty string) are all equivalent and can be compared against each other:

```
var c = (false == 0); // true
var d = (false == ""); // true
var e = (0 == ""); // true
```

The falsy values null and undefined are not equivalent to anything except themselves:

```
var f = (null == false); // false
var g = (null == null); // true
var h = (undefined == undefined); // true
var i = (undefined == null); // true
```

Finally, the falsy value NaN is not equivalent to anything — including NaN!

```
var j = (NaN == null); // false
var k = (NaN == NaN); // false
```

You should also be aware that `typeof(NaN)` returns "number". Fortunately, the core JavaScript function `isNaN()` can be used to evaluate whether a value is NaN or not.

***If in doubt…***
Use strict equal (===) and strict not equal (!==) in situations where truthy or falsy values could lead to logic errors. These operators ensure that the objects are compared by type and by value.

```
var l = (false == 0); // true
var m = (false === 0); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular expressions are like JavaScript expressions with the following differences:

**Context**: JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the global window. In Angular, expressions are evaluated against a scope object.

**Forgiving**: In JavaScript, trying to evaluate undefined properties generates ReferenceError or TypeError. In Angular, expression evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null.

**Filters**: You can use filters within expressions to format data before displaying it.

**No Control Flow Statements**: You cannot use the following in an Angular expression: conditionals, loops, or exceptions.

**No Function Declarations**: You cannot declare functions in an Angular expression, even inside ng-init directive.

**No RegExp Creation With Literal Notation**: You cannot create regular expressions in an Angular expression.

**No Object Creation With New Operator**: You cannot use new operator in an Angular expression.

**No Bitwise, Comma, And Void Operators**: You cannot use Bitwise, , or void operators in an Angular expression.

[Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Answer (score 0):

Before Angular 1.2.7,

> expressions that were a function with one or more arguments evaluated to
>   true, but functions with zero arguments evaluated to false.
>
> This behavior seems both unintentional and undesirable. This patch makes a function
>   truthy regardless of its number of arguments.

Please find the github link: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/01c5be4681e34cdc5f5c461b7a618fefe8038919