# which is better to get rid of undefined

Tags: javascript

How to get ride of undefined in single condition?

```
 var test;
 // the value of test may be null, undefined,0,1,true,false,or any other string
 if(!test){
  // it fails when test =true;
 }

 if(!!test){
 // it fails when test =0;
 }
```

Is there any other way to satisfy all theses cases in single condition

Comment: what is the wanted result of the given values?

Comment: you should learn about truthy and falsy values in JS. check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44260206/6567275

Comment: `typeof` ... thats all...

Answer (score 1):

To check if the variable *test* is not defined and is not null the code should look like this:

```
var test;

if (typeof test !== 'undefined' && test !== null) {
   console.log('the variable *test* is not defined and is not null');
}
```

Comment: actually the condition should not allow both undefined and null values.